# parse json to generate table out of two objects

Tags: json, jq

In my bash script, I have the following json from curl.

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Critical"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Error"
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      35
    ],
    [
      31
    ]
  ]
}
```

I would like to print it out in a table format like:

```
Critical: 35
Error: 31
```

Comment: sorry, the formatting is wrong while i was editing.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?  How did it fail?

Comment: @Inian, i was blocked by pairing the row with data. i was thinking to do a bash loop, but asked to wonder if there is better idea.

Comment: Whatever be the efforts and whatever stage it may be in, post that, so it gives an impression that the question author made an effort towards solving. Some people might improvise on your attempt to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `.rows` and `.data` into an array, and feed that to `transpose` filter to pair each *row* with its corresponding *data*. Then for each pair, generate strings of name-datum pairs by means of string interpolation. E.g.:

```
[.rows, .data] | transpose[] | "\(.[0].name): \(.[1][])"
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/P6FtwJx8mH)</sup>

Comment: sorry, this is a simplified version, and there are actually more fields than the rows and data.